# Discord.py bot recognising own messages even when it is told not to

Tags: discord, bots, discord.py

I was trying to make a bot that if a message had certain keywords in it, it would say "why would you say",themessage,"?"  but it recognises it's own messages so i tried to fix that but it still does. Here is my code:

```
import discord
from discord import user
client = discord.Client()
keywords = ["help", "william", "William", "Monkey", "monkey", "Monkaee", "monkaee", "monkae","Monkae"]
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    for i in range(len(keywords)):
        if keywords[i] in message.content:
            message2 = "Why would you say", message.content, "?"
            if message.author.id == "750809710739062804":
                await message.channel.send("shut it botty", delete_after=5)
            else:
                await message.channel.send(message2, delete_after=5)
```

then my token but i'm not gonna put that in. the id is the bot's id so it shouldnt recognise its own message but it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing an Integer to a String

```py
    if message.author.id == "750809710739062804":
```

Try it without the quotes, like this:

```py
    if message.author.id == 750809710739062804:
```

Also, if you're trying to concatenate strings you should use

```py
     message2 = "Why would you say" + message.content + "?"
```

Instead of

```py
     message2 = "Why would you say", message.content, "?"
```